# nginx ingress redirect traffic

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress

I deployed nginx ingress controller and randomApp to minikube cluster.
I have 2 requirements:

1. All traffic for "random/.*" should go to the random service
2. Other paths should go to the nginx.

This configuration is correct?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: path-rule-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: ingress-nginx-controller
      port:
        number: 80
  rules:
  - host: random.localdev.me
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /random/(.*)
        backend:
          service:
            name: random
            port:
              number: 8000
        pathType: Prefix
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add `metadata.annotations: kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"` or `spec.ingressClassName: nginx` to allow nginx-ingress-controller to discover the ingress.

Also you shouldn't define default backend service as ingress-nginx-controller. Because you will get `503 Service Temporarily Unavailable` since `nginx-ingress-controller`'s `nginx.conf` didn't be configured for this. You can give another nginx server's service for it.

Comment: Nginx ingress deployed also nginx service "ingress-nginx-controller-admission".  So, now is it correct?

Comment: apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: path-rule-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: ingress-nginx-controller-admission
      port:
        number: 80
  rules:
  - host: random.localdev.me
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /random/(.*)
        backend:
          service:
            name: random
            port:
              number: 8000
        pathType: Prefix

Comment: Yes, it looks good. If you handle incoming $1 in service: random, it redirect and render the content. But I'm not sure defaultBackend for '/' will work as I said in the answer.